# Control serialization of GWT

Tags: serialization, gwt

I want GWT to not serialize some fields of my object (which implements Serializable interface). Normally, transient keyword would be enough. However, I also need to put the object on memcache. The use of transient keyword would make the field not being stored on memcache also.

Is there any GWT-specific technique to tell the serializer to not serialize a field?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GWT Serialization can be disabled on a field by using GwtTransient annotation. (It's in gwt-user.jar)

Comment: +1 This is awesome, I never knew about this. Thanks for finding it!